# Wrap and Protect executable

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper

I'm working on a copy protection software and I'm trying to create a wrapper around any kind of executables (managed and unmanaged). This wrapper will then try to execute the wrapped executable without writing it to the disc like normal, and execute it with `Process.Start()`.

I used .Net 4.0 Assembly and Appdomain to get it working, but as I've read and tested, it will only work with .Net executables. How would I go around and execute any kind of executable without writing it "naked" to the drive?

Can I execute it from within an encrypted compressed file for example?
or MemoryMappedFile?

Comment: AFAIK normal executables are not written to disc before execution. I don't know about .Net. Anyway, ALL executables need to be in RAM in machine code (this means unencrypted and uncompressed) to be executed.

Comment: @m0skit0 - .NET Applications work similar to normal executables.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to start it with Process.Start() - you could load the program into memory and then do a jmp to it's start address, but there's probably all kinds of horrible security issues around doing this.

Comment: To execute them, they have to either be on disk, or loaded, completely, uncompressed and unencrypted into memory. I think you can then just call the entry point and it'll do the rest. I think doing it from .NET is a bit of a stretch though...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Really you are wasting your time. You CANNOT stop someone from copying your executable, getting your code, or anything else. Even if you can perfectly protect the executable file on disk, the moment it starts running, someone can use a debugger to make a dump of the executable, even from a memory mapped file. This is how products like Xenocode, or .NET Reactor, or any other packer for that matter, are defeated.

The better option for you is to stop and think about what it is that you are really trying to achieve. Are you concerned about people violating a license agreement? Are you worried about your software appearing on The Pirate Bay? If you make useful software, both of these things are eventualities, not possibilities. Protect your software with copyright, and your algorithms with patents, if appropriate. Then you have legal recourse to go after violators.

Sorry to burst your bubble, but there is no technical solution that cannot be defeated. Dongles can be emulated, web services can be patched around, encryption keys can be sniffed, etc. Spend your time making your software great, not trying to protect what cannot be protected.

Comment: +1; If your software is worth pirating, it will be regardless of your protection. If it's not, then there's no need to protect.

Comment: I guess your right, I will rethink this. The idea was to control the launch of an exe through a wrapper. But I it's looks like impossibility as you said. Well I guess the another idea would be to encrypt the exe and then the wrapper will just decrypt it and write it to the disc the very first time of launch. Note, wrapper get approval from a server to do this.